# Correct spacing in the alignat*-environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, alignat

The following code is given:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) = 0.25 & -  0.00 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) = 0.50 & -  0.25 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) = 0.75 & -  0.50 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) = 1.00 & -  0.75 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) = 1.00 & -  1.00 & = 0
\end{alignat*}
```

which outputs
[image: align-environment]
The output however should have the same spacing between each number like the first equation `h(x) = g_s(x) - g_s(x - 1)` has. (In other words, the spacing between the minus sign is too small.) How will I obtain this result?

Comment: as always it's easier to test if you provide a test document not a fragment, but use `{}=`

Comment: I will take this into consideration for my next posts, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways depending how you think of it `{}-` forces a binary - but you could view the form as only having right hand sides of the second and third groups so if you mark the empty lhs with `&&` then the `-` at the start of the right hand sides get the usual space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,nicefrac}

\begin{document}

aaa
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) = 0.25 & -  0.00 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) = 0.50 & -  0.25 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) = 0.75 & -  0.50 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) = 1.00 & -  0.75 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) = 1.00 & -  1.00 & = 0
\end{alignat*}

bbb
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) = 0.25 & {}-  0.00 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) = 0.50 & {}-  0.25 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) = 0.75 & {}-  0.50 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) = 1.00 & {}-  0.75 & =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) = 1.00 & {}-  1.00 & = 0
\end{alignat*}

ccc
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) = 0.25 && -  0.00 && =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) = 0.50 && -  0.25 && =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) = 0.75 && -  0.50 && =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) = 1.00 && -  0.75 && =  \nicefrac{1}{4}\\
    h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) = 1.00 && -  1.00 && = 0
\end{alignat*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between b) and c) or do both variants produce exactly the same result?

Comment: @Doesbaddel same result  here as your numbers are same width but change the `0.75` to `0.7` and you will see the `&&`  version keeps them left aligned wehereas your original and the `{}-` version right aligns them. I think `&&` is better actually but...

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 5):

Using `{}=` solves the spacing issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) = 0.25 & {}- 0.00 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) = 0.50 & {}- 0.25 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) = 0.75 & {}- 0.50 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) = 1.00 & {}- 0.75 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) = 1.00 & {}- 1.00 & = 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE using <code>\tfrac</code> instead of <code>nicefrac</code>.]

(I do not have the package `nicefrac` installed. I would recommend to use `\tfrac` instead of `\nicefrac`. Most mathematicians prefer a horizontal fraction bar.)

**Edit**

Here is another version that might make more sense with respect to the structure of the content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) && = 0.25 - 0.00 && = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) && = 0.50 - 0.25 && = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) && = 0.75 - 0.50 && = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) && = 1.00 - 0.75 && = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) && = 1.00 - 1.00 && = 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) shows yet another version for placing the delimiters in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496971/82324) to this question. All versions have pros and cons, and it depends, e.g., on the format of the numbers and the other content, which one is best.

Answer (score 4):

A `tabstackengine` approach.  Here, the `\TABbinary` forces the leading negatives to be considered binary, the `\setstackalingap{}` allows the horizontal gap between align groups to be eliminated and the `\setsatckgap{L}{}` allows for the baselineskip to be set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicefrac,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\setstackaligngap{0pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\alignCenterstack{
h(0) & = g_s(0) - g_s(0 - 1) = 0.25 & - 0.00 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(1) & = g_s(1) - g_s(1 - 1) = 0.50 & - 0.25 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(2) & = g_s(2) - g_s(2 - 1) = 0.75 & - 0.50 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(3) & = g_s(3) - g_s(3 - 1) = 1.00 & - 0.75 & = \nicefrac{1}{4} \\
h(4) & = g_s(4) - g_s(4 - 1) = 1.00 & - 1.00 & = 0
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]